# Computing $\int_{\gamma}e^zdz$, where $\gamma$ is a particular semicircle

Tags: complex-analysis, contour-integration

> How can I compute $\int_{\gamma}e^zdz$, if $\gamma$ is the semicircular arc depicted below?

[image]

So, $\gamma=3e^{i\theta(t)}$, with $0\le\theta(t)\le\pi$, and then $$\displaystyle\int_{\gamma}e^zdz=\int_0^\pi e^{3e^{i\theta(t)}}\cdot\left|\left(3e^{i\theta(t)}\right)'\right|dt .$$

This looks awful, how can I compute the rest?

Comment: Do you know Green's Theorem, or Cauchy integral formula? With this theorem, you get that the answer is $-\int_{-3}^3 e^t dt = e^{-3}-e^3$.

Comment: @Crostul you mean $\int_{\gamma}f(z)dz=F(\pi)-F(0)$ where $F$ is a primitive of $f$ ?

Comment: @OBDA Reading Travis's answer, perhaps Crostul meant that if you close the path along the real segment of line $\;[-3,3]\;$ , then you can apply Cauchy's Theorem in this *closed* path, and the integral on the real segement is very easy to calculate.

Comment: @OBDA My comment was supposed to follow Travis' answer. Of course all of this does not make sense if you want to use the definition of the path integral to compute it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint** Consider the integral of $e^z$ around the closed contour given by concatenating $\gamma$ with the line segment from $-3$ to $3$ (oriented rightward), and apply [Cauchy's Integral Theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy%27s_integral_theorem).

Comment: why a concatenation ? can I not use the formula in the comment above ?

Comment: @OBDA I think you can apply the formula you mentioned in your questions...and good luck trying to solve it!

Comment: @OBDA Like Timbuc says, it's not obvious how to evaluate the given real integral you produced in the question. As for concatenating with another path, that's because Cauchy's Integral Theorem requires a closed contour, whereas $\gamma$ itself is not closed. Another way to think about C.I.F. is this: Since $e^z$ is analytic, the value of a contour integral of that function depends only on the endpoints, not the path itself, so we may as well replace the given contour $\gamma$ with a straight-line path connecting its endpoints.

Answer (score 1):

$F(z) = e^z$ is an anti-derivative of $f(z) = e^z$. Just use the (complex version of) the fundamental theorem of calculus.